# How can i check the assembly version of a dll file that is stored on one of my iis websites and not on my local machine?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have a dll file that iv'e put on my IIS website.  Is it possible to check the assembly version from this file.  I know how to do this if the file was stored on my local machine but its not. this is the code i tried:

`string FilePath = ""; 
 FileVersionInfo VersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(FilePath); 
 string productVersion = VersionInfo.FileVersion;`

The problem i'm getting is that when i enter a website directory in my FilePath variable it errors and says you can't enter a website path. Is there another way to use a website as a path and not a directory from my c drive??
If it is possible please give me a starting point and some websites to learn this from or some sample code.  Would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve"? What is going to be doing the retrieving?

Comment: If you know how to get the assembly version (_italic_know how to do this if the file was stored on my local machine_italic_) then just have a web page (for diagnostic purposes, accessible only to site administrators) listing all the assemblies (loaded modules) and their versions.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but **_you need to help yourself first_. :-)** **[do more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527)**, if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide an [MCV Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/5827005) that explains the best ways to contribute to StackOverflow.

Comment: I meant check the assembly version of this file sorry. Ive tried this code

Comment: string FilePath = "";
 FileVersionInfo VersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(FilePath);
 string productVersion = VersionInfo.FileVersion;

Comment: but when i enter a website's path's in the FilePath variable it seems to error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### URL <> FileSpec

Thanks for telling us what you've tried. Sounds like you are trying to reference the DLL by the URL, not the file spec. A path like this:

http://MyNetworkWebServer/assy.dll

goes thru IIS and HTTP which **intentionally bars actually viewing the dll** for many reasons - the dll will be coded to serve up some content maybe but certainly not allow you to examine the bits.

A path like this:

\\MyNetworkServer\IisFileShare\assy.dll

goes thru the filesystem / filesharing areas of the server and **will** allow you to call those functions **if** proper permissions and security settings are in place.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpfull